# Multiple priority date options

Tags: priority-date-options

I have filed four provisional patent applications disclosing various and improving embodiments of the same invention. The second, third and fourth provisionals include new material, as well as all material of the preceding  application.

I filed the four in a cumulative way so that I may have multiple priority date options to choose from according to how early the money for a non-provisional PCT application becomes available.

Question:
Do I indeed have the freedom to claim any one of four possible priority dates for my non-provisional application, as long as I file within the 12 month deadline of the chosen priority date?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you filed 4 patents on more or less the same invention without claiming priority to each other? Aren't you worried they might get used as prior art for each other? I know the US is kinda different there, but I don't think EPO will be that forgiving.

Comment: You can claim the various priority dates for relevant content only when the non-provisional is filed.

Answer (score 1):

**Do I indeed have the freedom to claim any one of four possible priority dates for my non-provisional application, as long as I file within the 12 month deadline of the chosen priority date?**

No. Your Convention application (such as a PCT application) must claim priority to (and therefore be less than 12 months after) the earliest application.

This is clear from the [Paris Convention art 4(C)(2)](http://www.wipo.int/wipolex/en/treaties/text.jsp?file_id=288514#P83_6610), which provides:

> These periods [for claiming priority] shall start from the date of filing of the first application; the day of filing shall not be included in the period.

The only way around this is if the original filing was irrevocably withdrawn *before* any of the later ones were filed. This is provided by art 4(C)(4).

However, the 12 months for the additional improvements start with each new filing (since that is the first filing for those improvements).

Comment: Thank you for that crucial information! I would have replied earlier but was not sure that 'add comment' was the way.

Comment: It means that I have far less time than I thought to raise the required funds and to file; but it will be done. It is amazing that this important information had escaped my attention though I have been reading on patent-related matters for many years.

Comment: The question by DonQuiKong has signaled the need for further clarification of the previous answer by Maca, who said:                                                                "However, the 12 months for the additional improvements start with each new filing (since that is the first filing for those improvements)."                                             Does this statement mean that material disclosed in the first application expires on its anniversary date for the purpose of a non-provisional application, and becomes prior art in relation to material added later?

Comment: @LukeLisle No. A provisional application can never be prior art for anything.

Comment: Are provisionals not published then? B because if they are, they are prior art when published and at least for novelty normal unpublished applications are prior art too, I don't know how provisionals are handled though.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Provisionals are published in the normal course of things:they are only published if they are used for a non-provisional (or as a priority document in another country, I guess). I was a little flippant before about saying provisionals are not prior art: they are indeed prior art once published (as with any document). But they are not prior art, and can never be prior art, if no non-provisional is ever filed.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Normal unpublished applications are not prior art, since prior art requires publication (35 USC 102(a)(2)). When they are published, they are deemed to have a prior art date of their filing date (or their provisional date). But if they are not published for whatever reason, they don't count.

Comment: Well as the US is now first to file, concerning novelty they do matter even if unpublished (?) Or can somebody else claim the same invention if the prov. Is dropped?

Comment: In response to the original question of this thread, Maca advised:                                         "No. Your Convention application (such as a PCT application) must claim priority to (and therefore be less than 12 months after) the earliest application."                                                                                  This seems to imply that the answer is 'yes' with regard to a non-convention non-provisional (a national US utility application as opposed to an international application). Am I correct?

Comment: @DonQuiKong "Or can somebody else claim the same invention if the prov. Is dropped" - Yes, since there's no prior art.